# Ionic Delete File using Native URL

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using [CSDK image](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/phonegap-plugin-csdk-image-editor) editor to edit the image. Here is the method to edit the image:-

```
CSDKImageEditor.edit(success, error, imageUrl, options);
```

So on success method editor is returning the image url, that's in native format like:-

```
content://media/23
```

I need to delete that file after editing. So I am using [Cordova File](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-i-use-cordovafile-to-delete-and-upload-file-that-create-by-cordovamedia-newmedia/13533) to delete the file. As this is native url so cordova file can't find the file using that url. After going through google I got a plugin [Corodva Filepath](https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath) to convert native url to file url, But this plugin is not working. After installing the plugin I can't build the file.

So the question is, I need to delete the file and I don't have file url, I have only Native url. Please suggest me something so I can delete the file using native url or I can convert the Native Url to file url in Ionic1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem with [Filepath Plugin](https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath). All I had just removed the last commit and It's working fine. On last commit only permission has been added, so I don't think it will affect your app.

Answer (score 6):

Hybrid applications do not have direct access to file System. This is a reason why you cannot use `content://media/23`.

You can use [cordova-plugin-file by Apache](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) to access to file and [this Post](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/28/how-to-delete-file-with-cordova) how to delete it:

```
var path = "file:///storage/emulated/0";
var filename = "myfile.txt";

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(dir) {
    dir.getFile(filename, {create:false}, function(fileEntry) {
              fileEntry.remove(function(){
                  // The file has been removed succesfully
              },function(error){
                  // Error deleting the file
              },function(){
                 // The file doesn't exist
              });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please check my question, I don't have file path all I have is native path.

Comment: Then how can I delete that using cordova file plugin?