# Delete file from file system in ionic 4

Tags: file, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working with one application in which I am creating offline PDF and save them in file system.
Now the problem is when I delete the particular record I need to delete the PDF from file system I go through the file plugin but couldn't find any method related to that. I am using ionic 4 here are some peace of code.

```
if (this.plt.is('cordova')) {
      this.pdfObj.getBuffer((buffer) => {
        const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        // Save the PDF to the data Directory of our App
        this.file.writeFile(this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Downloads/', 'ACCSYS-' +
        this.randomString(4) + '-' + encodeURI(this.headerData.title) + '.pdf', blob, { replace: true }).then(fileEntry => {
          // Open the PDf with the correct OS tools
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.hideLoader();
            this.fileOpener.open(fileEntry.nativeURL, 'application/pdf');
            this.pdfObj = null;
          }, 1000);
        });
      });
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.hideLoader();
        this.pdfObj.download();
        this.pdfObj = null;
      }, 500);
    }
```

Assume I store the nativeURL in localstorage.

any idea how to delete the file ??

Comment: Which plugin are you using for file system access? Is it the [File plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file) ?

Comment: yeah I am using file and fileopener plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a `fileEntry` object you can use the `remove()` method to delete the file like this:

```
fileEntry.remove(function() {
    // if the file has been successfully removed
}, function(error) {
    // if there was an error removing the file
}, function() {
    // if the file does not exist
});
```

See these links for more [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) and [examples](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/28/how-to-delete-file-with-cordova).

Answer (score 1):

here is the perfect way to do it ( define window on the top of ts file )

```
delete() {
    // this.fileHelper.removeFile();
    const fileToRemove = this.remoteURL; // Change this with your file path
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( fileToRemove,  (dirEntry) => {
      dirEntry.remove(this.successHandler, this.errorHandler);
    });
  }
  successHandler() {
    console.log('Directory deleted successfully');
  }
  errorHandler() {
    console.log('There is some error while deleting directory')
  }
```

Comment: found this answer very close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069764/ionic-delete-file-using-native-url